# How to change "on" property for philips hue via httpclient in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am making a http.post request using angular's httpclient. I will send a body with the property "on" = true or false. Since these request for changing the value of a property are quite similar in url syntax for Hue, I want to make it generic.

I have found something where I have a variable

```
 private lightProperties = {};

  stateOn: boolean;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  toggleLights(lightNumber: number) {
    this.getLightState(lightNumber).subscribe(data => this.stateOn = data.state.on);



    this.lightProperties['on'] = !this.stateOn;
    this.httpClient.put(
      `${this.hueApiUrl}/${lightNumber.toString()}/state`, this.lightProperties)
      .subscribe(data => data);
  }
```

It works but I don't quite see how this line works?

```
this.lightProperties['on'] = !this.stateOn;
```

I don't know if this is better?

```
const body = {
      on: !this.stateOn
    };
```